# K-mean clustering label problem

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I am doing K-mean clustering by SKlearn. And I have a question about the clustered labels. Is it possible to keep the same label number if a new cluster is entered? For example, If I have a data set ran by K-mean clustering below:

```
data            cluster
0.424              0
1.142              1
2.785              1
3.478              2
  ...             ...
```

Now I want to maintain the cluster 2 with data 3.478. However, the cluster label will be changed if a new cluster is entered:

```
data            cluster
    0.424              1
    1.142              2
    2.785              2
    3.478              3
    10.11              4
    ...                ...
```

How can I maintain the same label number if there is a new cluster entered？

Comment: You cannot. Because a "maintained" by new data points cluster is not exactly that "same" cluster as it was before. Clustering (classic methods such as k-means) is blind to whatever labels preexist. And the program labels clusters in its cluster solution just arbitrarily.

Comment: When you've added more points to a cluster, in what sense you think the cluster is the same?

Comment: @ttnphns I want to achieve the prediction on new data with the fixed cluster label. For example, I need to do further manipulations on all new input data with clustered result of label 3. However, since the label number is always changing with new data, how could I achieve it?

Comment: If you need to assign new data to old clusters you don't have to redo clustering. Just enlist the new point in the cluster whose centroid is the nearest. But if that distance appears unusully big that may mean the point is an outlier and should not be enlisted at all.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you. That brings me some good inspirations

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that. Firstly, because your old cluster assignments will not be the same as the new cluster assignments. You can only try to define a mapping afterwards (not saying this is easy), which may not be successful if the two runs significantly differ.

Comment: The reason I want to achieve the fixed label number is I want to predict a new data with output of cluster 3 only. If the label is always changing, how could I achieve the prediction with the fixed output label?